# How do I differentiate between databases when using e.g. sequence

Tags: liquibase

I just started using [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org) and stumpled upon the problem to differentiate between the capabilities of different databases.

We would like to support multiple databases (Oracle, MySQL, Derby - to name three).

The all have different capabilities. In specific Oracle supports `sequences` whereas MySQL and Derby do not.

When I let hibernate generate the DDL I can choose different dialects and it will consider these different capabilities and generate a `Sequencer` when using Oracle and use a plain table (for ID-generation) when using Derby or MySQL.

Now, I know I can constraint changesets by specifying '`oracle`' in the `dbms` attribute. But then how can I do the plain table solution for the other databases? There does not seem to be a 'not oracle' attribute for `dbms`.

How does anyone else handle this? (I could not find anything about it on the liquibase pages nor on the forum.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a [precondition](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/preconditions.html) on the changset. Boolean operations are supported.

For example

```
 <preConditions onFail="CONTINUE">
     <or>
         <dbms type="oracle" />
         <dbms type="mysql" />
     </or>
 </preConditions>
```

Comment: Thx for your help Mark.
I already found the `preConditions` but that means I have to list all databases that do not support `sequences`. If liquibase extends the list of supported databases (or one non-sequence-supporting db does support this in a future version) I would have to think of this and extend the list. I was hoping that there is a less "have to think about it again" solution.

Comment: Oh, maybe now I get what you meant by boolean operations are supported: You can add `<not>` to this like this: `<not><dbms type="oracle"/></not>`.

Comment: Yup, that was what I meant. Either way you'll have to maintain some sort of list. Databases that do (or do not) support sequences. A truly cross-platform schema is not without challenges :-)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to put all your sequences in a changlog file which you `include` in your main changelog, and then do something like this:

```
<changeSet
    dbms="oracle,db2,db2i"
    author="mccallim (generated)"
    id="1419011907193-1"
>
    <createSequence
        schemaName="${main.schema}"
...
```

That changeset only gets executed for the DBMSs listed.