# Liquibase DB Independent Insert statements

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, liquibase

I have a schema for Oracle/MySql/PostgreSql defined using Liquibase. I have some insert statements. Now I want to write the `<insert>` tag that would support all three DBs, such that if it is MySql, it would use the auto-increment feature, and sequence for Oracle. Can I achieve this without duplicating the `<insert>` tag?

Comment: To be completely cross platform will always mean you have to support the least common denominator in terms of features.... You understand that using auto-increment means you don't know the primary key of the record, hence it becomes difficult to provide rollback logic for your changeset?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think it's even more of a pain than you think. I believe you have to do this with different changesets. See [How do I differentiate between databases when using e.g. sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246009/how-do-i-differentiate-between-databases-when-using-e-g-sequence).

So you would have:

```
<changeSet id="x" author="y">
  <preConditions>
    <dbms type="oracle"/>
  </preConditions>
  ...
</changeSet>
<changeSet id="xx" author="y">
  <preConditions>
    <dbms type="mysql"/>
  </preConditions>
  ...
</changeSet>
<changeSet id="xxx" author="y">
  <preConditions>
    <dbms type="postgres"/>
  </preConditions>
  ...
</changeSet>
```