# Handling of multiple parameter values in liquibase

Tags: liquibase

We are going to use liquibase parameter values to control the column types on multiple supported database engines. I would like to be able to specify the column types in the changelog file. Firstly for all the dbms and (i.e. something from java.sql.Types.*) and then overwrite it for some specific ones.

It could look like this:

```
<property name="DATETIME.type" value="TIMESTAMP"/>
<property name="DATETIME.type" value="DATE" dbms="oracle" />
```

But Liquibase seems to take the first found parameter value (so on oracle the TIMESTAMP type is taken in the above example). 
Could I reliably reach the desired result by simply changing the order of the lines like this?:

```
<property name="DATETIME.type" value="DATE" dbms="oracle" />
<property name="DATETIME.type" value="TIMESTAMP"/>
```

EDIT:
What I'd like to archive, is to support new databases without a need of changing the types mapping - so to use the liquibase default (java.sql.Types.* types) for databases, for which no compatibility with our legacy db-versioning tool is required.

Answer (score 0):

I have asked a similar question on how to differ between databases in liquibase [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11246009/332248).

Though it was about sequences I think the same approach could be used to handle different column types:

```
<changeSet id="1" author="bob">
    <preConditions onFail="CONTINUE">
        <not>
            <dbms type="oracle" />
        </not>
    </preConditions>

        // contents of your changeset here
        <property name="DATETIME.type" value="TIMESTAMP"/>

</changeSet>
```

Comment: We currently have more then 1500 change sets in the changelog, imported from our db. I cannot imagine, how to implement database independency that way.
Our Oracle "Integer" is represented with "Number(9)" and not Number(10), "LONGVARBINARY" with "IMAGE" on mssql. And I have to ensure compatibility of liquibase versioning with our previous legacy db-versioning tool.

Comment: I think - generally - the database independency is (or should) already be built into liquibase itself so you would not have to think about it at all. Liquibase comes with database dialects and while it parses your changelog it translates the database to the right datatype for the specific database. This is how it is supposed to work. But if you have requirements that require other types you probably have to use something like `preConditions` to handle it.

Comment: One other approach might be to use the extension system that liquibase offers and overwrite the default type handling with your specific requirements. But I don't know if the extension system allows you to intercept the type handling...